# PHP/CURL Empty Reply from Server

Tags: php, curl, post

I have a NodeJS App running on my server and i have a CURL that submits a post request to where the app's port on my server. I am able to normally do it if i visit the PHP page, but trying to execute it as a command line is a different story. It keeps returning with the HTTP response code 0 and the error being "Empty Reply from Server"

PHP Curl (OOP) [$this->domain = http://domain:port , $url = /path/to/something]:

```
protected function post($url, $data)
{   
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->domain.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //error_log(curl_error($ch));
    return $result;
}
```

Command Line Execution:

```
curl https://rbx.shopping/Secure/IPNCron.php
```

Default page when visiting domain:port

[image: Default Page when visiting domain:port]

Example on what should be returning:
https://rbx.shopping/Bot

Answer (score 0):

try to add cookie jar:

```
$ckfile = tempnam (sys_get_temp_dir(), rand().'cookiename');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
```

Also add this:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');
```